# Getting back to my application after sending sms using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I have been searching for this, found many threads specifying on this. But things are not working for me. Tried setting "exit_on_sent" and also tried using startAcitivityForResult. Here is the code snippet I was trying with

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumbers)); // phoneNumbers is a list of phone numbers to which i need to send messages at the same time
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", context.getResources().getString(R.string.message_body));
sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: First, use `ACTION_SENDTO`, as is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Messaging). Second, please explain **in detail** what "things are not working for me" means.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried with your suggestion and used ACTION_SENDTO instead of ACTION_VIEW, but my problem is that after sending the message, my application is not resuming from where I called the intent. The messaging application is visible even after sending the message. My requirement is to go back to my application after sending message.                                                                                  
NB: I want user interaction to send message and also i want to send message to multiple people in a single shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My requirement is to go back to my application after sending message.

When you use `ACTION_SENDTO`, or `ACTION_VIEW`, or other `Intent` actions, you are launching a third-party app to go do something. In this case, you are launching a third-party app to send an SMS message.

There are ~2 billion Android devices in use, spread across ~10,000 device models. There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of different pre-installed SMS clients across those device models. Users are also welcome to install other SMS clients from the Play Store or other app distribution channels.

What happens when your app starts up one of those hundreds of SMS clients **is up to the developers of those SMS clients, not you**.

If you want control over the entire user experience, send the SMS message yourself, using `SmsManager`, as [Ankit pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695253/115145). If you want to use the user's preferred SMS client, stick with `ACTION_SENDTO`, but what happens at that point is up to the SMS client developers and the user, not you.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But is it possible to send message to multiple people at a single shot with out looping while using SmsManager like what I do through sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto: 5375;894959;4545433;"));

Comment: @Rino: "But is it possible to send message to multiple people at a single shot with out looping while using SmsManager" -- no. I do not know why you fear a loop.

Comment: Unfortunately I want to send message on user confirmation only, because its optional to send message or cancel and the message should be send to multiple people.

Answer (score 1):

You can send SMS silently using SMSManager. as following :

```
       try {

            String ph="1234568790";
            String msg="Hello";

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(ph, null,msg, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message not Sent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: No..i want user interaction to send message and also i want to send message to multiple people in a single shot.